# uses-sdk is missing in manifest

Tags: android, android-studio

i am following the Training section of developer.android.com where i can read :

> One of the most important elements your manifest should include is the
>    element.

But, the automaticaly generated manifest i have is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.david.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
            android:name="com.example.david.myapplication.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Where i can't see any .
Must i consider it as normal behaviour ? Must i add this by myself ?

May be usefull : i am using AndroidStudio instead of Eclipse/ADT

Comment: If you're using Gradle, check your build.gradle file

Answer (score 5):

Android Studio uses the newer Gradle-based build system. Its [manifest merger](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/manifest-merger) creates the actual manifest for you, based on the information in the `AndroidManifest.xml` files and `build.gradle` files.

In particular, the `uses-sdk` information is usually derived from `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 0):

For android studio, the compile sdk version is in the build.gradle. like this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.eyespage.sdk.accounts"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

so you don't have to include it in manifest